# how to fill a second combobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to fill a second combo for Turkey?
When selecting the first combo turkey,    Ankara  Izmir filled  to second combo.

```
String[] s = {"Turkey", "Rusia", "Italia"};
        for (String string : s) {
            comboBox.addItem(string);
        }
        String x = String.valueOf(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("Turkey")) {
            String[] s1 = {"Ankara", "Izmir"};
            for (String ss : s1) {
                comboBox1.addItem(ss);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have to play with DeafultComboBoxModel(s), to prepare required number of array, then from ItemListener to change array in another model and finally to add another model to another JComboBox, nothing else, btw a few times here about

Comment: please whats did you mean with "?"

Comment: Please show an example?

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjcombobox%5D+two+model)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ActionListener to the first combo box to perform an Action when an Item is selected.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<String, String[]> subItems = new Hashtable<String, String[]>();

    public ComboBoxTwo()
    {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox<String>( items );
        mainComboBox.addActionListener( this );

        //  prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        add( mainComboBox );

        //  Create sub combo box with multiple models

        subComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        add( subComboBox );

        JButton arrow = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, subComboBox, "Text", "");
        Dimension d = arrow.getPreferredSize();
        System.out.println(arrow.getClass());
        System.out.println(d);
        d.width = 35;
        arrow.setPreferredSize(d);

        String[] subItems1 = { "Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

        String[] subItems2 = { "Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

        String[] subItems3 = { "Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = (String)mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get( item );

        if (o == null)
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        try
        {
//          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ComboBoxTwo() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       //Add this import
         import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

         DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();           

      String[] s = {"Turkey", "Rusia", "Italia"};
      // set the datamodel for the second combo box

       jComboBox2.setModel(dcm);
         // in the action perform method of the compbo box, add this code


      private void comboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    String x = String.valueOf(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
    if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("Turkey")) {
        String[] s1 = {"Ankara", "Izmir"};
        for (String ss : s1) {
            dcm.addElement(ss);
        }
     jComboBox2.setModel(dcm);

  }
```

Comment: How can I make the data been stored in MySQL db, when I add new data by using this Java swing?

Comment: Ask it in a separate  question after you have  searched google properly

Comment: Can I you ask ?